# Connector vs. Adjunct

Tags: grammar

Doesn't an infinitive phrase placed at the beginning of a sentence anaphoric to something mentioned previously in the discourse make it a connective (sentence connector)?

Example:

> He wants to be a singer. **To achieve this goal**, he is working very hard.

Here "To achieve this goal" can be said to be a sentence connector. 
Otherwise, it will be only a purpose adjunct,
which can be placed at the end of the sentence.

Can "To achieve this goal"/"to this end" be called sentence connectors?

Comment: I think the "sentence connector" would be best exemplified here by *He wants to be a singer, **and** he is working very hard to achieve this goal.* Where we'd normally discard the second instance of the predictably repeated subject ***he***.

Comment: I would see "[in order] To achieve this goal," as a free modifier.

Answer (score 2):

The *to*-infinitival examples given are both simply adjuncts of purpose. They are linked to the preceding text anaphorically by *this*. They are interpreted roughly as:

> To achieve this goal (of being a singer), he is working very hard.

Connective adjuncts that also serve to mark a semantic relationship (other than ordering, addition and comparison, elaboration and exemplification or informational status) between the clause they introduce and the preceding text are called **impure connectives** (CaGEL p777-779). They don't have any elements that anaphorically link to the preceding text. Examples for those that show purpose are: *accordingly, as a result, consequently, hence, in consequence, so, therefore, thus*.

Comment: This sounds masterly, but ELU requires linked and attributed references to accepted grammars, articles etc to (1) indicate whose particular analysis and terminology is being put forward, (2) give a hint as to level of scholarship involved (Strunk & White? McCawley?), and (3) facilitate further research by visitors to ELU..

Comment: Thanks DW 256.'to this end''for this purpose'etc are classified as  connectors which does the same work(anaphoric reference to preceding sentence) as 'to achieve this'. So,  Prepositional phrases acting as connector in similar structure wheres 'infinitive phrase ' being used only as purpose adjunct leaves one bit befuddled about the logic. Any comment on this?

Comment: I have no idea about a category of words called 'connectors'. Connective adjuncts are a concept introduced and outlined in CaGEL. Different categories of phrase can, of couse, perform similar functions in various structures.